# How to sync slash commands in every server my Discord bot with discord.py is in?

Tags: discord.py

for the past few months i've had a bot i programmed with discord.py and i gave up motivation for it around november, this is because i can't figure out how to get slash commands in every guild the bot is in. i've searched everywhere, and want to know the answer know. very confusing stuff ngl ig im just not programmer chad enough

i tried other methods such as putting the guild as a variable, one by one with each test server i have just to see if it'd save, it saved to the UI of / but on the servers where the variable's id wasnt set on it didnt work but the one did

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to setup with only one method by discord.py
You can do sth like this in your "main.py" file:

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
  def __init__(self, *, intents: discord.Intents):
    super().__init__(intents=intents)

    self.tree = app_commands.CommandTree(self)

  async def setup_hook(self):
    # sync to a specific guild
    test_guild = discord.Object(id=...)  # change ... to your test guild_id
    self.tree.copy_global_to(guild=test_guild)
    
    # sync to all servers if no specification
    await self.tree.sync() 


intents = discord.Intents.default()  # intents (you can set it whatever you like)
bot = MyBot(intents=intents)

# TOKEN is your bot token generated from developer portal
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

You can check the documentation for more details. 
sync: [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.sync) 
copy_global_to: [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=copy_global_to#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.copy_global_to)

Comment: ty but one issue idk how to make it with @tree.command (the thing i use for my commands)

Comment: @polysteel If you want to do it in this "main.py" file, you could put the decorator as `@bot.tree.command()`

Comment: Don't auto-sync, especially not globally

Comment: why shouldn't i autosync

Answer (score 0):

> this is because i can't figure out how to get slash commands in every guild the bot is in.

> one by one with each test server i have just to see if it'd save, it saved to the UI of / but on the servers where the variable's id wasnt set on it didnt work but the one did

This means you have **registered** the commands to these specific guilds, and then **synced these specific guilds**.

If you want **global** commands, don't add them to any guilds, and sync globally instead of to a guild.

```py
await tree.sync() # Syncing without an argument syncs your global commands
```